# Logistic Regression and Scipy Optimization with fmin_bfgs

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, machine-learning, scipy

I am trying to implement Logistic Regression and I am using Scipy's Optimize module to find the optimized theta values. I am able to get the correct value when using the fmin function. But I would like to do so when using the fmin_bfgs function which requires the gradient.

Here is a code snippet:

```
#Returns Cost of current theta values and gradient of cost w.r.t theta.
def costFunction(theta, X, y, _lambda):

    #Initializes useful variables
    m = len(y)
    grad = np.zeros((np.shape(theta)))

    #Solves for Hypothesis for input X.
    h_x = Sigmoid(np.dot(X,theta))

    #Reshaped because numpy kept returning row vector, not column.
    h_x = h_x.reshape((m,1))

    #Cost is broken up into terms for simplicity. 
    term1 = -y*np.log(h_x)
    term2 = (1-y)*np.log((1-h_x))



    #Regularized Cost FUnction
    J = (1/m) * sum(term1-term2) + (_lambda/(2*m)) * sum(np.square(theta[1:][:]))

    #Gradient for Theta1
    grad_reg = (_lambda/m)*theta[1:]

    #Combines gradient for Theta1 and onward. 
    grad = (1/m)* (np.dot(np.transpose(X),(h_x-y))) + np.vstack(([0],grad_reg)) 

    return J,grad 





#Finds Optimal Value for theta
cost, grad = costFunction(initial_theta, X,y, _lambda)
opt_theta = fmin_bfgs(cost,x0=initial_theta,fprime=grad, args = (X,y,_lambda))
```

The error I get is  `'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable`which comes from the `function_wrapper` function in the optimize module. I even tried returning the gradient and the cost in two different functions, but got a `vstack` error of some sort(if that matters/helps at all).

As far as I can see I have provided what the optimization function ask for.

**EDIT/UPDATE:** I realized that the error I was getting was because I was passing the cost, and grad numpy arrays as parameters when it was expecting a function to return those parameters. I realize that I could create a wrapper function? to get both of those values without using two separate functions, but for temp purposes, I changed costFunction so it only returns the cost, and created a whole new function,`Grad()`, (with identical code though) that only returns the grad. This gives me the  `all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly` vstack error again.

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to debug things without a minimal reproducible example.

The way I'd debug it, I'd start with something trivially simple to make sure I get the basic syntax right. There are several ways of using bfgs minimzation with an explicit gradient. First, no gradient information:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: from scipy.optimize import minimize

In [3]: def f(x):
   ...:     return np.sum((x-2.)**2)
   ...: 

In [4]: x0 = np.ones(3)

In [5]: minimize(f, x0, method='bfgs')
Out[5]: 
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 4
    nfev: 20
     fun: 1.6656677750444977e-16
       x: array([ 1.99999999,  1.99999999,  1.99999999])
<snip>
```

Now, with gradient, you can either have a callable which returns the function *and* the gradient:

```
In [6]: def f_and_jac(x):
   ...:     val = np.sum((x-2.)**2)
   ...:     grad = 2.*(x-2.)
   ...:     return val, grad
   ...: 

In [7]: minimize(f_and_jac, x0, method='bfgs', jac=True)   # notice the 'jac' parameter
Out[7]: 
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 4
    nfev: 4
     fun: 0.0
       x: array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])
```

Alternatively, you can set `jac` to a callable, which should have the same signature as the cost function and return the gradient:

```
In [8]: def jac(x):
   ...:     return 2.*(x-2.)
   ...: 

In [9]: minimize(f, x0, method='bfgs', jac=jac)
Out[9]: 
  status: 0
 success: True
    njev: 4
    nfev: 4
     fun: 0.0
       x: array([ 2.,  2.,  2.])
```

Comment: I took you advice on reproducing something simple, so I had the gradient function spit out what the first gradient should be. The values are correct, but there seems to be an odd spacing. It is: `[ -0.1        -12.00921659 -11.26284221]`. In between the first two values it has an odd spacing. I went to where the vstack function error is and it apparently receives a tuple which I printed out. It was `([0], array([[ 0.],
       [ 0.]]))` before a flatten method, and `([0], array([ 0.,  0.]))` after a flatten method. How do I get that to be one single array?

Comment: This is not really helpful. Best break your question into separate ones: there's clearly one about minimization itself, and a separate one about the cost function.

Comment: Alright, well the one I intended this for apparently, is how do I get `np.vstack(([0],grad_reg))` to return a single array? Not something like `([0], array([ 0., 0.]))`?